# select option selected by 2 times jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(".treatment-btn").click(function()
{
    $("#treatmentModal").modal('show');
    $('.treatment-form')[0].reset();
    $('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option[value=""]').attr("selected", "selected");
}); //when i click on this button it resets form successfully but select option is not reset.

function makeEditHtml(response) {
var price = response[0].treatment_price.split(".")[0];
var cent = response[0].treatment_price.split(".")[1];
$("#treatmentModal #treatment").val(response[0].treatment_name);
$("#treatmentModal #price").val(price);
$('#treatmentModal #cent option[value='+cent+']').attr("selected", "selected");
$('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option').removeAttr("selected");
$('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option[value='+response[0].treatment_duration+']').attr("selected", "selected"); //i select it again at here after ajax call
$.each(response, function(i)
{
    $("#treatmentModal input[type=checkbox][value="+response[i].worker_id+"]").prop("checked",true);    
});
$("#treatmentModal").modal('show');
}
```

// and this is called when ajax request fires i append data in same form but select box value not selected. it is showing correct in firebug but not display on screen. first time it is working fine

Comment: Could you please create a working fiddle or snippet to replicate the problem?

Comment: No i cant it have big code

Comment: He means [creating a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). The reason why you can't have more code is because you are not describing your problem, but only posting a blob of code.

Comment: okie let me create it

Comment: Sounds like you are not preventing the default action of the form so your page is just posting back - have a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Yeah problem got solved now.. i make mistake here `$('#treatmentModal #treatment_time 
  option[value='+response[0].treatment_duration+']').attr("selected", "selected");` i change it to `$('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option[value='+response[0].treatment_duration+']').prop("selected", true);
 } ` and it is working fine for me now Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your click function code to below. To reset select you can simply set its value to blank.

```
$(".treatment-btn").click(function()
{
   $("#treatmentModal").modal('show');
   $('.treatment-form')[0].reset();
   $('#treatmentModal #treatment_time').val("");
 });
```

Change the other code accordingly. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it is helpful but not working with it.. i just post my answer i solved it. Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i make mistake here

```
function makeEditHtml(response) {

 $('#treatmentModal #treatment_time 
  option[value='+response[0].treatment_duration+']').attr("selected", "selected"); //i select it again at here after ajax call 
   //i replace it with this below line and it is working ok now
   //$('#treatmentModal #treatment_time option[value='+response[0].treatment_duration+']').prop("selected", true);
 }
```